VBA Loop I want to Terminate Function if there is no data
this might not be the right way to go about this, but I have a workbook that is running between a couple of programs pulling data and formatting it. One of the things I can't get past is that one of the programs is feeding in a few lines of data that I don't want. Unfortunately I don't know that program (Rocket Terminal / Also known as Attachmate Xtreme) well enough to stop the data.
What I have done is created a loop that deletes these rows. Now what I would like to happen is if there is no data where it is looking to copy that it would just terminate the function and continue through the high level loop that is calling that function. I think this would be easy but I am missing something obvious.
Sheets("Report Data").Select

Dim DeleteRowData As Long
Dim DeleteRowCounter As Long

Set DataSheet = Sheets("Report Data")
With DataSheet
     DeleteRowData = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

     For DeleteRowCounter = DeleteRowData To 1 Step -1
          If .Cells(DeleteRowCounter, 3).Value = "TYP   " Then
              .Rows(DeleteRowCounter).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
     Next
End With
    
Range("A2:I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

Sheets("Report Formatting").Select
Range("A1:I1").PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False


this might not be the right way to go about this, but I have a workbook Seems like you want to delete rows where the Column C text has "TYP   ". If yes, then you do not need a loop. You may want to use Autofilter to delete all of them in 1 go... In the referred post, I am copying the rows, you can simply delete instead...

You need to supply a little more pieces of information, I think... 1. Supposing that the respective program fills rows at the end of existing, would it be a correct supposition? 2. Looking to your code, it seams that this program also write a kind of marker ("TYP   ") in column "C:C". Is this understanding correct? 3. Do you need to delete only lines containing the marker and after that to exit the loop? 4. Is it possible that after some lines added by the respective application to also appear some lines from another one, which must be kept?

You may also want to see How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

@FaneDuru 1. Yes the program copies line by line into excel. 2. Yes you are correct. 3. Yes, I need to delete those lines, then check for data and exit both the loop and the function it is contained in if there is no remaining data. 4. Yes these extra lines of data are typically scattered among real lines of data. So the way I have it will delete those and then carry out several formatting actions and end up saving and printing a report.  However, if there is no remaining data there is no reason to continue. I wonder if the easiest thing to do would be another loop to check if value is "".

Well, the fourth issue explanation will not make my answer working as you need ("scattered among real lines of data"). I will adapt the code to deal with that, but avoiding iteration. I will place a filter on that specific column. It should analize if all rows contain the marker and in such a case exit Function (Apropos, is it really a function? Since it does not return anything, is can be a Sub...).

Did you test my updated answer? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Just insert Exit Function into the appropriate spot in your code. This will exit the current function and allows the code that called that function to continue.

Please, try the next updated code:
Sub StopExitFunction()
  Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, rngTYP As Range, boolAllDel As Boolean, lastRow As Long
  
  Set DataSheet = Sheets("Report Data")
  If DataSheet.AutoFilterMode Then DataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False: 'Stop
    With DataSheet.UsedRange.Columns(3)
         .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="TYP   "
         On Error Resume Next 'to avoid an error if no filtered rows exist...
          Set rngTYP = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
         On Error GoTo 0
         
         If Not rngTYP Is Nothing Then
            If rngTYP.cells.count = .rows.count - 1 Then boolAllDel = True 'if all rows contains "TYP   "
            rngTYP.EntireRow.Delete 'delete rows
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove the filter before exiting
            If boolAllDel Then Exit Sub 'in case of all rows containing "TYP   "...
                                        'if it is a Function, use Exit Function...
         End If
         .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove the filter and go on
    End With
    
    lastRow = DataSheet.Range("C" & DataSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on C:C

    DataSheet.Range("A2:I" & lastRow).Copy
    DataSheet.Parent.Worksheets("Report Formatting").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 'why PasteSpecial without any parameter
                                                                              'and not Paste if you need format, too?
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox "Job done..."
End Sub

The above code is a Sub. Not returning anything, why to be a Function? If any reason to keep it as a function, adapt the procedure name in this way...
